# How to implement floating context panel like Gmaps 6

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I want to implement a floating context panel like that found in Google Maps 6 when you open 'My Places' or do a directions search. (Admittedly, my experience of this is only on a Nexus7 tablet). The example image below shows the panel I mean.

Can anyone show me how these are done please?

[image: Example Gmap "My Places" floating panel]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply showing and hiding a layout (the context panel) which is arranged as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
    <MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ...
    />
    <MyContextView
        android:id="@+id/the_context_view"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:visibility="hidden"
        ...
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Show and hide it using View.setVisibility().

Comment: I'm assuming "MyContextView" is a LinearLayout with some stuff in it? Also this android:visibility property doesn't seem to exist..

Surely when you 'show' this view it will mess with the current layouts on the screen? What I was really expecting was something along the lines of a CSS float:left..

Comment: Yes, MyContextView can be any View subclass you like. Visibility: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility. It won't mess with the current layouts because it's a child of a RelativeLayout, and children of a RelativeLayout can overlap (with the Z order determined by the order they're added).

Comment: Thanks. I had read the parent container should be a FrameLayout! Any reason to use Relative over Frame? Also, I'm not sure why I get compile errors with android:relative - I'll look into it later.